# Python coverage.py exclude_lines

Tags: python, regex, django, code-coverage, coverage.py

### Background

I have a couple Django projects that I use coverage.py with and have been trying to add some additional expressions to the exclude_lines portion of my .coveragerc configuration file. The problem is that even with proper regex that works at picking up the line in a tester such as http://www.pythonregex.com or http://www.regexr.com it doesn't result in the lines being ignored in the report.

I've reviewed the [docs](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/config.html) and poked around the [repository](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy) but haven't been able to dig up any reasoning to why the config I have might not be working. From the docs it appears I have the config exactly as they describe it should be.

I've also attempted to use [django-nose](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose) version 1.2, the last PyPI release, which would allow [exception injection](https://medium.com/@echohack/python-unit-testing-injecting-exceptions-with-mock-and-nose-e46bf579c867) but to no avail, it appears to have some issues with figuring out the coverage of Django views and Django REST Framework API endpoints at least in version 1.7.

### What I've Tried

My configuration is as follows:

```
[run]
branch = True
omit =
    */tests*
    */migrations/*
    *__init__.py*
    */settings/*
    *wsgi.py*
    *admin.py*

[report]
# Regexes for lines to exclude from consideration
exclude_lines =
    pragma: no cover
    def __repr__
    if self.debug:
    raise AssertionError
    raise NotImplementedError
    (.*)except Exception as e:(.*)
    if 0:
    if __name__ == .__main__.:
```

I've also tried the following combinations for the exception handling in the report section of the config:

```
(.*)except Exception as e:
except Exception as e:
except Exception as e:(.*)
```

An example of a function with the portion of code I expect to be ignored is below:

```
def my_func():
    try:
        # Some logic
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        return defensive_exception(my_func.__name__, e, False)
```

In the above example, based on the documentation, I would expect everything under the `except Exception as e:` to be ignored or at least the `except Exception as e` line itself. However this doesn't appear to be the case. If anyone has some insight into what is wrong with my configuration or what I need to do differently I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: The problem is that you now need to exclude multiple lines but `exclude_lines` is intended to exclude one line at a time. It also doesn't know where to "end" the code underneath the exception. Lastly, if you do this, you won't learn whether there are any issues in your exception handling code so it's probably better to write tests to increase coverage there.

Comment: As mentioned I'd be happy if it only excluded a single line but it doesn't even exclude the `except Exception as e` line. I have tests that test the code below the exception handling for each of the instances that it is used in so I'm not afraid of it failing. Also as I pointed out all known exceptions are handled above the `except Exception as e` handler and are already tested. As for not knowing where to stop, the (.*) regex stops at the new line break so that should at least ignore that one line. I've also updated the question to reflect my attempts at using django-nose.

Comment: After looking back at django-nose it appears there have been some merges into the master branch since the last release so I will look into those but I would still like to understand the issues with my present configuration.

Comment: Personally I'd recommend against the usage of Django-Nose, the project is hardly maintained and prone to breaking. I've recently switched most of my projects to pytest with pytest-django.

Comment: @devonbleibtrey I'm concerned that you have "except Exception" lines in your code, *and* that you want to exclude them from testing?  This seems like a dangerous model.  Why do you want to blanket-catch exceptions, and why don't you care if that code is tested?

Comment: @NedBatchelder I've taken your advice and spent additional time investigating each of the locations I had except Exception and have ensured that all of the exceptions that can be thrown are handled explicitly. For poorly documented ones I have started some threads with the corresponding communities to try and expand on the documentation and better understand the packages. By doing so I have eliminated any locations that cannot be reached by our testing suite. I'll still attempt to get a reproducible test together that shows the issue of custom lines in the config that I'm seeing and email you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to match the entire line, so there is no need for the dot-stars at the end.  This should work:

```
[report]
# Regexes for lines to exclude from consideration
exclude_lines =
    pragma: no cover
    def __repr__
    if self.debug:
    raise AssertionError
    raise NotImplementedError
    except Exception as e:
```

**THAT SAID**: this style of coding concerns me a great deal.  Catching blanket exceptions as you are doing is bad style and can hide problems.  Then you seem to not care if that code is tested!

If you need to perform strong exception handling across a large number of functions like this, perhaps you want to write a function decorator to wrap the function call.  That will reduce the number of lines of code, and centralize your logic.  Then you can deal with the coverage issues in one place also.

Comment: I like the recommendation of the decorator. I'll transition to that. I've tried that variant of the configuration file and it doesn't seem to work. Based on the searching I've done it appears most people default to using `pragma: no cover` which would work fine in your decorator suggestion. I've been looking through the repo to find a test that proves the functionality out but could only find some verifying that cov.config.exclude_list was populated. But I'm probably missing something.

Comment: I don't see any reason why that regex wouldn't work.  If you want my help to debug it, make a reproducible case, and email it to me.

Comment: thanks again for the help on this. Sorry I didn't respond to your concerns back when I originally brought this up. You are totally right that using `except Exception as e` is a bad and risky implementation. We had used that implementation because a package we were using was throwing undocumented exceptions and were still figuring out what each of them were. That being said we transitioned to a better maintained package, and also started contributing to packages when potential exceptions were not documented, rather than taking the above lazy, risky approach. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7):

What I always do is use `pragma: no cover` for this which you already have in your `exclude_lines`.

```
def my_func():
    try:
        # Some logic
        return True
    except Exception as e:  # pragma: no cover
        return defensive_exception(my_func.__name__, e, False)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's an option but I'm looking for a way to not have to add comments everywhere I have this line. One could make the argument that it would be an additional check to make sure that only the tested code is located below the handler but still doesn't answer the question as to why the configuration setup doesn't work.